# Where clause to change according to NULL parameter?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a stored proc that takes several parameters, two of which allow nulls.

```
param1 = null [name]
param2 = null [id]
```

I want to implement the following logic:

```
if param1 is null then where clause = (where col2 like param2)
else if param2 is null then where clause = (where col1 like param1)
else where clause = (where col2 like @param2 and col1 like param1)
```

`Param1` and `param2` allow nulls but one must be filled out.  If both `param1` and `param2` are left blank then no output is expected.  I just can't get the syntax right.

Comment: Q: What is your question?  Q: What language are you using?  T-SQL?  Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea what the question in there is, but I'll offer:

```
where ( param1 is not NULL or param2 is not NULL ) and
  ( ( ( col1 like param1 ) or param1 is NULL ) or
  ( ( col2 like param2 ) or param2 is NULL ) )
```

Comment: @Matt: If this actually helped you out, please consider [accepting the answer formally](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work "How does accepting an answer work?") then.

Comment: @HABO - you're a better man than I for divining what was being asked for ;)  Good job!

Comment: I think there's a tiny flaw in this solution. I think it should be *"... (col1 like param1 or param1 is NULL) **and** (col2 like param2 or param2 is NULL)"*, because, if both params are not NULL, the OP wants rows to match them both.

Comment: @AndriyM - I do believe you're right. That must be why it wasn't accepted as an answer.